# Is every connected metrizable locally path connected space a length space?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Does every connected metrizable locally path connected topological space $X$ admit a compatible metric $d$ so that $(X,d)$ is a length space?

(**Edit to correct definition:** Recall that a metric space $(X,d)$ is a length space if for every $x$ and $y$ in $X$ and every $e>0$, there exists a rectifiable path from $x$ to $y$ whose length is less then $d(x,y)+e$.)

The answer is certainly *yes* for Peano continua, but this is not a trivial fact.

More generally the answer is apparently *yes* for such locally compact spaces, but local compactness is certainly not necessary: for example, familiar Hilbert space is a length space.

Do the above claims survive without local compactness?

Comment: There is something wrong with the inequality on $f$. Take $t=0$ for example.


Comment: Thanks Sergei! My obtuse (and likely incorrect) definition should be ignored. The reader should use any standard definition of length space. For example, for all x and y in X and all e>0, there exists a rectifiable path from x to y whose length is less then d(x,y)+e.

Comment: @Paul: I have incorporated your comment into the statement of the question, so as to hopefully correct the definition.

Answer (score 9):

This is not an answer but a long comment with references for the **locally compact case**. It is proved in [Tominaga-Tanaka, Convexification of locally connected generalized continua. J. Sci. Hiroshima Univ. Ser. A. 19 (1955), 301–306] that

**Theorem.**
*Every locally compact, connected, locally connected, separable metrizable space admits a complete length metric.*

The proof is similar to the one in the compact case which is due to Bing and Moise (independently). A relative (stronger) version is due to Doodley [Further extending a complete convex metric. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 40 (1973), 590–596] and [Extending a complete convex metric. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 34 (1972), 553–559] whose electronic versions can be easily found on the web.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is no.  There is a metrizable version of the Tangent Disc Topology, namely where instead of extending the Euclidean topology in the upper half-plane to all of $\mathbb{R}$ you extend it to a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  This will be locally path-connected and connected (see *Counterexamples in Topology* by Steen/Seebach), but not locally compact, and as far as I can tell there will be no equivalent metric which is a length space.

To see this, pick just a single point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and adjoin to the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{H}^2$ neighborhoods of the form $D \cup \lbrace x \rbrace$, where $D$ is any open disc in $\mathbb{H}^2$ tangent to $x$, creating a topological space $(\mathbb{H}^2 \cup \lbrace x \rbrace, \tau)$.  Then if $C$ is the boundary of one of these tangent discs, points along $C$ *do not converge to* $x$ *in* $\tau$.  However, if $V$ is a vertical segment with endpoint $x$, then points along $V$ do converge to $x$, and clearly $V$ is a length-minimizing path.

If $c_n, v_n$ are points with the same $y$-coordinate along $C$ and $V$ respectively (assume *all* the $c_n$ are either to the left, or to the right, of $V$) with $v_n \rightarrow x$, then $|c_n - v_n| \rightarrow 0$.  Notice that the lengths of paths from $c_n$ to $x$ converges to zero (by triangle inequality and moving horizontally, then vertically), yet each $c_n$ lies outside the neighborhood $D \cup \lbrace x \rbrace$, impossible in a length space.

This last bit is the 'topological agreement' criterion, I'm not sure what it's normally called; see p. 27, no. (4) in *A Course in Metric Geometry* by Burago/Burago/Ivanov:

> If $x \in X$ and $U$ is a nbhd of $x$, then $\inf \ell(x, c) > 0$ for
> $c \in U^c$.

Especially there will be no equivalent metric that's a
length space, since an intrinsic length metric is topologically unique
and will have the same defect.

Hopefully this argument is right; even if there's a small error, I wanted to bump this question.  I'm not an expert in length spaces, perhaps replacing $x$ with $\mathbb{Q}$ is necessary, but those details seemed quite complicated.

Comment: Is there a rectifiable path to $x$ passing through all $c_n$?

Comment: I don't think so; I think if you draw consecutive segments of points approaching $x$ from the left (WLOG) with increasing $x$-coordinates and decreasing $y$-coordinates in the plane, then their angles should have to be bounded away from zero.  Here the topological invariance should be due to $c_n$ being on the boundary of a neighborhood (a 'tangent disc topology circle'), and this boundary also belonging to a 'Euclidean topology circle', and they agree except at $x$.

Comment: Oops, that probably needs to happen for every subsequence of the $c_n$, or at least in some limiting sense.

Comment: In fact I am confused now. In the hyperbolic metric, is not $x$ an ideal point? I mean, at infinite distance from any internal point of the open upper halfplane?

Comment: I don't think so; otherwise the space would be disconnected.  When I used "$\mathbb{H}$" I mean with the metric induced from the usual Euclidean one (though I suppose that theoretically it shouldn't matter, but then the arguments will be different).  Sadly I'm not an expert on this space, either xD  Someone will probably point out some technical issue(s) to deal with, then maybe we will have a clearer picture after sorting through them.

Comment: Also, a possibly relevant fact: The path components of a length space (in this case, the whole space) coincide with the 'finite distance components', i.e. maximal sets each of whose pairs of points can be joined by a finite-length path.

Comment: Hmmm don't know. There might be different topologies on that space. Maybe some of them are connected and not path-connected? I vaguely remember (I think from Ken Brown's book) that at least one of these is a CW-complex topology, but I believe that, say, the modular forms people use [a different one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model#Metric), with $(ds)^2=((dx)^2+(dy)^2)/y^2$

Comment: I think what you have proved is that the metric induced by the Euclidean metric on $H$ (how do you extend it on $H\cup \{x\}$ ?) is not intrinsic. Why does this mean that there is no equivalent intrinsic one?

Comment: The Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{H}^2$ is already a length metric (it's convex).

Comment: For example, take a straight line emanating from $x$ to the left, but tangent to, $C$.  Then points on this line converge to $x$, as do the points on $V$, and they are getting arbitrarily close to each other, as seen just by taking horizontal segments.  But by the topological agreement criterion, points along $C$, which are contained in these horizontal segments, will have to have horizontal distance from $V$ bounded away from $0$.  This violates the triangle inequality on the horizontal segments.

Comment: but again this way you only prove that the extended Euclidean metric is not intrinsic. Also, please use @username when responding, because i wasn't aware of your reply (you are aware of mine, because it is a comment under your post)

Comment: @erz But this configuration is along neighborhood boundaries, so should be topological.  It's not supposed to be a complete proof, someone with more experience in length spaces can either finish the details or show that it's not a counterexample, and maybe the same for extending along $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of a point.  But I think this space should work.  No other relevant space in Steen & Seebach fails to have an intrinsic metric, so if these spaces do then maybe it's true after all.  Maybe an analogue where $\mathbb{H}^2$ is replaced by some wild manifold could be interesting as well.

Comment: ok, but then please indicate clearly that this is just a suggestion of a counterexample (i agree, it seems plausible, but i am afraid the proof is pretty far at this point)

Comment: @erz IMO it's already obvious from the wording of the post, e.g. "if this argument is wrong" and "I think" etc.  Also I feel it shouldn't be very far off (assuming it's correct); the argument I gave in the comment about 'midpoints' of the horizontal arcs not converging to $x$ while both sets of endpoints do seems on the verge of a complete proof, I am just waiting for a length space expert to give the final OK and 'precise statement'.

Comment: Again, your argument seems to rest on the choice of the Euclidean metric on $H$. In particular, it is not clear why the length of horizontal segments converge to $0$