# When do Polish spaces admit complete metric making them $\mathrm{CAT}(\kappa)$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, non-positive-curvature

---

### **Question**

$\DeclareMathOperator\CAT{CAT}$Let $X$ be a Polish space.  When are there known conditions under which $X$'s topology can be metrized by a metric $d$ such that $(X,d)$ is a:

1. $\CAT(\kappa)$ space with $\kappa>0$,
2. $\CAT(0)$ space,
3. $\CAT(\kappa)$ space with $\kappa<0$.

*For definitions/background see below...*

---

### **What I Known**

**CAT(0) Case:**

This question is related to the following posts: [(MSE - Answered) When $X$ admits a metric making it into a $\CAT(0)$ space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041020/existence-of-cat0-metrics/1061666#1061666):
The summary of that answer is:

- If $X$ is a contractable topological manifold with boundary then its interior (as a manifold) admits a complete $CAT(0)$ metric [see this reference](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-45/issue-1/Interiors-of-compact-contractible-n-manifolds-are-hyperbolic-ngeq-5/10.4310/jdg/1214459752.full).  The linked article also states that if $X$ is PL-manifold and tame then such a metric exists.

**CAT(1) Case:**
This open (and old) MO post: [(MO) When $X$ admits a metric making into a $\CAT(1)$ space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190621/topological-spaces-admitting-cat1-metrics) gives some positive answers when $X$ is polyhedral (but the [linked article](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dan&paperid=10154&option_lang=eng) is in Russian...)

---

### **Background**

In what follows, we use $M_{\kappa}$ to denote the simply connected Riemannian manifold of dimension $2$ with constant curvature $\kappa$.  For example, $M_0$ is the Euclidean plane, $M_1$ is the surface of the unit sphere, and $M_{-1}$ is the hyperbolic plane.
Let
$$
D_{\kappa}:=\operatorname{diam}(M_{\kappa})
=
\begin{cases}
\pi/\sqrt{\kappa}&:\, \kappa >0\\
\infty &:\, \kappa\leq 0
\end{cases}
$$

**Definition:** *Comparison Triangle*.  Let $(X,d)$ be a geodesic space, $x_1,x_2,x_3\in X$ and let $T$ be a triangle in $X$ whose edges are geodesics connecting $x_1$ to $x_2$, $x_2$ to $x_3$, and $x_1$ to $x_3$.  A *comparison triangle* $T^{\star}$ in $M_{\kappa}$ for $T$ is a triangle in $M_{\kappa}$ with vertices $y_1,y_2,y_3$ such that $d(x_i,x_j)=d_{M_{\kappa}}(y_i,y_j)$ for $i,j=1,2,3$.

**Definition** *$\operatorname{CAT}(\kappa)$-space* A [*geodesic* metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_metric) $(X,d)$ is if *$\operatorname{CAT}(\kappa)$* if for each geodesic triangle $T$ in $(X,d)$ with perimeter at-most $2D_{\kappa}$ there is a comparison trianble $T^{\star}$ in $M_{\kappa}$ with sideos of the same length as those of $T$ and such that the distances between points in $T$ are no more than those in $T^{\star}$.

Further discussion can be found [here](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/%7Efptac/images/Workshop/Fernandez.pdf) or in Martin R. Bridson Andre Haefliger's [book: Metric Spaces of non-positive curvature](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/%7Ebarakw/rigidity/bh.pdf).

Comment: Is this question useful without a link to the definition of CAT($\kappa$) ?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I added some definitions, backgrounds and links; I hope this helps my question reach a wider audience.

Comment: The way it is asked, it is just a subquestion of my old MO question. A better question would have been with two parts: for CAT(-1) and for CAT(0) metrics.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Why?  Since $\kappa\in \{-1,1\}$ is just a special case for some $\kappa \in \mathbb{R}$.  Do you mean to separate the three different phases: $\kappa=-1,0,1$?

Comment: The following properties of a topological space $X$ are equivalent: (1) There exists $k\in {\mathbb R}$ such that  $X$ admits structure of a CAT(k) space.(2) $X$ admits structure of a CAT(1) space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan so every $CAT(-1)$ space admits the structure of a $CAT(1)$ space?  I didn't know this; may I ask for a reference?

Comment: @Carl_Petterson Every CAT(-1) space is a CAT(1) space: This is an easy consequence of the definition and comparison of hyperbolic and spherical triangles. Should be in Burago-Burago-Ivanov book. I will check.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Did you ever happen to find an answer to your original post?

Comment: @Carl_Petterson: No.

Comment: A partial answer is given in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190621/topological-spaces-admitting-cat1-metrics/460763#460763